# React this.props.children is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following router config:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={History.createHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={Page}>
      <IndexRoute component={OverviewDashboard}/>
      <Route path="/:env" component={Env}>
        <IndexRoute component={EnvOverview}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('page'));
```

and the following component definitions:

```
const Page = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <main>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    );
  }
});

const OverviewDashboard = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <section>
        <Env name="Env1" />
        <Env name="Env2" />
       </section>
     );
  }
});

const Env = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <section className="env">
        <header>{this.props.params && this.props.params.env || this.props.name}</header>
         {this.props.children}
       </section>
     );
   }
});

const EnvOverview = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Jobs env={this.props.params.env}/>
        <Runtime env={this.props.params.env}/>
      </div>
    )
   }
 });
```

I've ommitted the definitions of `<Header>, <Jobs>` and `<Runtime>` because they are not relevant.

When i go to `/` link `{this.props.children}` within `<Env>` component is undefined and thus not rendered.

However when I go to "/Env1" `{this.props.children}` is set to `<EnvOverview>` correctly and displayed.

I am new to React and probably I am using the routing component incorrectly. Could someone explain how do I render `<EnvOverivew>` also when accessing `/` link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to `/Env`, react-router renders your `/:env` route, whose component is Env. Inside this route, you have an `IndexRoute`. This `IndexRoute` renders the `EnvOverview` component as its parent route children. Thus, you get `{this.props.children}` on this case.

When you enter the `/` route, it triggers your `IndexRoute` inside `App`, whose component is `OverviewDashboard`. It doesn't enter the `/:env` route because you didn't provide a parameter to match `:env`.

Inside your `OverviewDashboard`, you are manually rendering two Envs, without providing their children ([check this](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children)). Thus, inside these two Envs, `{this.props.children}` equals `undefined`.

I don't know what your requirements are, but you could change the `OverviewDashboard` render method to this:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <section>
      <Env name="Env1"><EnvOverview name="Env1" /></Env>
      <Env name="Env2"><EnvOverview name="Env2" /></Env>
    </section>
  );
}
```

And inside `EndOverview` render method, change `env={this.props.params.env}` to `env={this.props.params.env || this.props.name}`.

I don't know if it's the best solution to your case, but I hope why `{this.props.children}` was `undefined` is clarified ;)

Comment: Thanks, you answer was very helpful. Now I need to understand what and when sets the `{this.props.children}`.